# Can i use the word "Repent" like this?

Tags: word-usage

> I repent what I did and will never do it again.
>
> I will hurt myself because I repent what I did

Are both these sentences correct? if not, kindly provide some simple examples of it's usage.

Answer (score 2):

Your use of "repent" is fine, but it's hard to say whether the word fits the context.  It's not enough to know *how* to use a word -- you have to also know when that word is *appropriate*.

"Repent" is a fairly strong term.  You might know from the [dictionary](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/repent) that it means

> feel or express sincere regret or remorse about one's wrongdoing or sin.

but you may not recognize that it really only is used for a *significant* transgression.  You would not casually say something like:

> I **repent** that I was late meeting you for lunch.

or, at least, not without irony.  Save "repent" for the big crimes, otherwise use something less extreme:  *be sorry, apologize, regret, be ashamed, be contrite, feel remorse, feel reproach,* etc.

In any case, just because you may "repent" something does not mean that you want to make amends for it.  "Repentance" and "atonement" are two separate things: "I repent" says you understand what you did was wrong, and "I want to atone" says you want to make it right.

I would say that "atone" better fits your second example.  Assuming the context is one of the more extreme religious sects that believes in purification through (self-inflicted) corporal punishment, a penitent might say:

> I will scourge myself to **atone** for my sins.

It's an odd practice in this day and age, but not one that has gone entirely out of fashion.  However, outside of this kind of limited context, saying that you seek atonement through self-molestation suggests you are *mentally ill*, and should get help.

Answer (score 1):

You should say, "I repent FOR what I did." "Repent" does not take a direct object.

I'm not sure what you're trying to say with the second sentence. Do you mean, the speaker is so sorry for what he did that he is considering injuring or killing himself? Grammatically, you could say, "I will hurt myself because I repent for what I did", but I don't think we would use the word "repent" in this context. It doesn't really make sense psychologically or theologically. To "repent" is to decide you need to change your behavior, not to punish yourself. You might say, "I am so filled with remorse for what I did that I will hurt myself", or "I feel so much guilt ..."

Comment: *"Confess yourself to heaven. **Repent what’s past**. Avoid what is to come."*  William Shakespeare, "Hamlet", Act 3 Scene 4 (among many others).  Anyway, my point is that "repent" can take a direct object, although it's common to say "repent *for*" something.

Comment: @Andrew And "repent of"

Comment: @EddieKal  Yes, that too.  Looks like there's a nice discussion over on ELU  https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/361272/is-there-a-difference-between-using-of-and-for-as-the-preposition-for-repen

Comment: @Andrew Thanks for the link! Very helpful discussion, and divided too!

Comment: @EddieKal  My opinion is that "repent of" is more formal, and sounds nice in certain contexts.  In most cases I wouldn't use either.

Comment: +1 For saying it should be *repent* ***for***. Whether it's grammatical or not to immediately follow the verb with a direct object, it's very awkward at the least, and would normally be rephrased.

Comment: I think "repent of" is more "King James/Shakespeare talk", old-fashioned English. Not that it wouldn't be understood.

Comment: @Andrew I just checked several dictionaries and most listed it purely as an intransitive verb, though one said it can be either. I think your "repent what's past" quote is more a poetic elision, but whatever.

Comment: @Jay _But Koresh refused to repent **of** his teachings, said Pace, who was leading a small house church in Gadsden, Ala., at the time of the 1993 standoff._ [USA today](https://www.usatoday.com/story/news/nation/2018/04/16/waco-25-year-anniversary-david-koresh/521276002/) _For example, in 1995, the Southern Baptist Convention publicly repented **of** its historical complicity with slave owners and passed a resolution for racial reconciliation_ [Vox](https://www.vox.com/2018/7/3/17527774/study-churches-racial-diversity-trump)

Comment: @EddieKal Ok, fair enough. I just did a Google Ngram and even for recent books, it appears "repent of" is much more common than "repent for". https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=repent+for%2Crepent+of&year_start=1950&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Crepent%20for%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Crepent%20of%3B%2Cc0

Comment: @Jay  The [Oxford dictionary](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/repent) has an example under definition 1.1  *Marian came to repent her hasty judgement*